# Price is not updating in all store views even though scope is set to global

Tags: magento-1.7, price, store-view, scope

We have multiple store views but we want prices to be universal across all stores views. We have the scope set to global but when I update prices either via upload through Magmi or manually it doesn't always update in all store views. I need to be able to update in admin or default store and it should change in all stores.

Can anyone please help me because I am getting one price in the product page and another price in the shopping cart on the front end. It seems like the product page gets the price from default store view and the shopping cart is taking from the admin values. I need them all to be in sync.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I spent days on figuring this out. But I finally got it done.

Actually it seems the product price scope is global - unless you have some kind of module which is overriding it. However the root of the issue can be found in catalog_product_entity_decimal table:

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal WHERE attribute_id = 75 // price attribute ID
```

If it shows you multiple rows for different store_ids you are facing the same issue like me. Because there should ONLY be one entry (one for store_id 0, if you set price to global and inherit the price from default scope).

**How to fix?**

1. Backup catalog_product_entity_decimal table
2. Run following query:

   ```
   DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal WHERE attribute_id = 75 AND store_id <> 0;
   ```

Please double check if price attribute id = 75 in your setup!

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug (or feature) in magento that when you change a price scope from website to global that even the system setting is applied the price and special price attributes will still have the website scope (take the values form the websites instead of the default).

You can alter this website scope to global in the database in table catalog_eav_attribute with the corresponding attribute ID's.
Value 2 is website and value 1 is global. So I set price, special price, cost and msrp to global (1). (maybe you should also consider to do that for the special price date attributes).

After that you should:
1.backup table: catalog_product_entity_decimal.
2.DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal WHERE entity_type_id = something AND store_id = something; (or not 0) This way you can delete all except 0 which is the default.
3. Run your price, attribute, product flat data index.
4. clear block and if available clear your fpc (full page cache)

Hope this helps anyone out there running into the same issue.

PS. don't forget that weight is also present in the decimal table so make sure the scope is global or filter it out in your query so it doesn't loose website specific values.